# YouTube embedded player throwing 401 errors

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the YouTube HTML5 embed player in an Angular app and I'm seeing these 401 errors pop up on page load (Chrome). Videos still play fine, but I'm wondering what's going on. I've tried pausing AdBlock and I see the same errors.

```
www-embed-player.js:301 POST https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9xx 401 ()

www-embed-player.js:301 POST https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_interaction?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9xx 401 ()
```

I've been using this code for months and haven't seen this until now.

This is the code that's failing:

```
function Ce(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
    function h() {
        4 == (k && "readyState"in k ? k.readyState : 0) && b && Pd(b)(k)
    }
    c = void 0 === c ? "GET" : c;
    d = void 0 === d ? "" : d;
    var k = se();
    if (!k)
        return null;
    "onloadend"in k ? k.addEventListener("loadend", h, !1) : k.onreadystatechange = h;
    k.open(c, a, !0);
    f && (k.responseType = f);
    g && (k.withCredentials = !0);
    c = "POST" == c;
    if (e = xe(a, e))
        for (var m in e)
            k.setRequestHeader(m, e[m]),
            "content-type" == m.toLowerCase() && (c = !1);
    c && k.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    k.send(d);
    return k
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API [401 error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) is defined as follows:

> This error indicates that the user has an unlinked Google Account,
>   which means that the user has a Google Account but does not have a
>   YouTube channel. Such users can access many features that are
>   dependent on user authorization, such as rating videos or adding
>   videos to a watch_later playlist. However, as an example, the user
>   would need a YouTube channel to be able to upload a video. A user who
>   has a Gmail account or an Android device is certain to have a Google
>   Account but may not have already linked that Google Account to a
>   YouTube channel.
>
> This error is commonly seen if you try to use the OAuth 2.0 Service
>   Account flow. YouTube does not support Service Accounts, and if you
>   attempt to authenticate using a Service Account, you will get this
>   error.
>
> The [YouTube API blog
>   post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html)
>   introducing Google Account support also discusses the
>   youtubeSignupRequired error in more detail. Although the blog post
>   explains the error for API version 2.1, the meaning of the error is
>   still applicable.